# Converting a 10 digit Int into Hex and then converting that to values in C

Tags: c, arrays, printf

For an exercise in C class, we are given an array of ints which contain 10 digits each:

```
unsigned int Array[] = { 1310740313, 1966096717, 2621456717 };
```

We are asked to print out a letter, a value in the 255 range and another value in the 65535 range.

We are using a little endian machine so we have to read from the right. I can figure out the answers by using conversions online but I can't figure it out using C code.

Do I get the hex value, store it, and then do a `printf` on each byte?

My current code looks like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ArraySize; i++)
{   
    printf("%x\n", Array[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
4e204f59, 7530414d, 9c40414d
```

How do I convert these to the letter and 2 number?

Comment: That's the instructions that were given...that's why i asked..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you looking for something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int Array[] = { 1310740313, 1966096717, 2621456717 };

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%c %d %d\n", Array[i] & 0xff, // last byte as char
                             (Array[i] & 0xff00) >> 8, // second byte as decimal
                             (Array[i] & 0xffff0000) >> 16); // last 2 byte as decimal
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Y 79 20000                                                                                                                                                                           
M 65 30000                                                                                                                                                                           
M 65 40000
```

Basically masking the byte(s) of interests and shifting them to the right place.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help!